# how to judge whether the parameters in URL in bottle?

Tags: bottle

for example, the URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/company?a=1
```

and how can i know whether the URL contains parameters a .

Comment: Wait, what?  What are you asking?

Comment: @Makoto, a is a parameter, i just want to know how to judge whether the URL has this parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you access `a`:

```py
@route('/company')
def company():
    if bottle.request.params.get('a') is not None:
        # param "a" was present in the URI's query string
```